# Literature on relationship between strong and weak* (weak star) convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I am trying to follow a proof in the paper [Wasserstein Generative Adversarial Networks by Arjovsky et al.](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/arjovsky17a.html) (proof A in supplementary material).

They show that the convergenc of the total variation distance of two probability distributions corresponds to convergence in a strong topology induced by the norm and the convergence of the Wasserstein-1 distance of two distributions corresponds to convergence in a weak* topology.

If I understand that correctly, the convergence of a sequence in a topology induced by the norm always converges strongly ([see here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/)). And convergence in a weak* topology is weak* convergence by definition.

As far as I understand this, strong convergence induces weak* convergence. I did also find that in some lecture notes (e. g. [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mazag/fa17/lecture9.pdf) or [here](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/handouts/weak.pdf)), but not in any textbook or scientific article. So does anyone know of literature I could cite in my thesis concerning this?

Or a proof that strong convergence induces weak* convergence (easily) understandable by electrical engineers would be fine, too, I guess.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to MSE.

The fact that strong convergence implies weak*-convergence in the dual space is so basic, that most books don't bother mentioning it. What might be a good thing to do is to reference "Functional Analysis" 2nd edition by Walter Rudin which is a good book on functional analysis containing a good introduction to the weak and weak* topology.

As for the proof, this consists of two parts, showing that strong convergence implies weak convergence and noting that weak convergence implies weak*-convergence.

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $X^{*}$ denote its dual space. By definition $X^{*}$ is the space of all continuous linear functional, so for any $\varphi\in X^{*}$ the operator norm
$$\|\varphi\|=\sup\{|\varphi(x)|:x\in X,\|x\|\leq1\}$$
is finite. 
Now suppose $(x_{\alpha})$ is a net in $X$ (or $(x_{n})$ is a sequence if you don't want to use nets) converging strongly to $x\in X$. Then for all $\varphi\in X^{*}$ we find
$$\lim_{\alpha}|\varphi(x_{\alpha})-\varphi(x)|=\lim_{\alpha}|\varphi(x_{\alpha}-x)|\leq\lim_{\alpha}\|\varphi\|\|x_{\alpha}-x\|=0.$$
As this holds for all $\varphi\in X^{*}$ by definition $(x_{\alpha})$ weakly converges to $x$.

For the next part it is important to note that the weak* topology is not defined on $X$ but $X^{*}$. So we are considering strong convergence on $X^{*}$ with respect to the operator norm, and a net $(\varphi_{\alpha})$ in $X^{*}$ weakly converges to $\varphi$ if for all $\psi\in (X^{*})^{*}$ we have $\lim_{\alpha}\psi(\varphi_{\alpha})=\psi(\varphi)$. Recall that $(\varphi_{\alpha})$ converges to $\varphi$ in the weak* topology if for all $x\in X$ we have $\lim_{\alpha}\varphi_{\alpha}(x)=\varphi(x)$. Note however that for $x\in X$ the evaluation map $\psi_{x}:X^{*}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\varphi\mapsto\varphi(x)$ is a continuous linear functional on $X^{*}$ hence $\psi_{x}\in(X^{*})^{*}$. Therefore if $(\varphi_{\alpha})$ converges to $\varphi$ in the weak topology it also converges in the weak* topology. (For a mathematical audience I would just write that the weak convergence   implying weak* convergence is trivial.)

Combining these two results gives that strong convergence on $X^{*}$ implies weak* convergence.

Let me know if any of these steps is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

***As far as I understand this, strong convergence induces weak$^*$ convergence... does anyone know of literature I could cite in my thesis concerning this?***

Yes: Proposition 3.13(ii) in [Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22To+avoid+any+confusion+we+shall+sometimes+emphasize%22&source=bl&ots=stlCR7GYh_&sig=ACfU3U2dUpTx1b_YX_ZeQnXLBZVbO5hZ6A&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv3uuhm5ngAhVIDrkGHVNfCLMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22To%20avoid%20any%20confusion%20we%20shall%20sometimes%20emphasize%22&f=false).